# Is MSN an OpenID provider?

Tags: openid, msn

Is MSN an OpenID provider? If so, do you know what the URLs look like?

I'm trying to add MSN to the list of providers with special buttons I already have for logging in to a web sit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has an OpenID service attached to Windows Live ID that [is in beta at the moment](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1791.entry?sa=554243812). Not every Windows Live ID user seems to be able to use it.

To use it, users have to [create an OpenID alias](https://login.live-int.com/beta/ManageOpenID.srf), where they will be provided an OpenID URL.

Comment: This is a *beta only* service (I don't mean like Google-perpetual-beta, I mean really BETA as in do-not-use-in-production).  It does NOT work for MSN, and besides it's shut down now.

Comment: I was not able to sign up for OpenID with any of three windows live accounts, all claimed wrong password, even right after loging in for hotmail. Maybe you have to be invited or something.

Comment: Thanks for the accuracy-edit, Pablo. Nice to see Stackoverflow at work :-) . –

Answer (score 0):

No.  MSN does not offer OpenID to its members.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Live ID OpenID CTP Status Update (August 2009)](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1791.entry)

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Live ID Added to RPX](http://blog.janrain.com/2009/04/windows-live-id-added-to-rpx.html). Have their plugin enabled in my WordPress blog, and I added Live ID as one of the sign-in options. Just tested it out, and it works for my Live Id :)