# What is the status of MSN openID integration?

Tags: openid, msn

One of the answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425314/) said that MSN OpenID was in Beta (as of September 2009). Does anyone know what is its *current* status? Has the integration been finished? If so what is the URL to perform a discovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the beta has ended, and now microsoft offers no support for OpenID.

During the beta, the url was `OpenID.Live-INT.com`, according to [this post](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1745.entry) on windows live id blog.